# Flutter setup MQTT with .p12 file

Tags: flutter, sockets, mqtt, iot, p12

I am currently rebuilding an App using Flutter, in the old iOS and Android app, both would fetch the `.p12` file from backend to setup the MQTT socket connection.

But the Flutter package I'm trying to use [mqtt_client](https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client) seems to require `useCertificateChain`, `usePrivateKey` and `setClientAuthorities`
three files like this:

```
SecurityContext context = new SecurityContext()
  ..useCertificateChain('path/to/my_cert.pem')
  ..usePrivateKey('path/to/my_key.pem', password: 'key_password')
  ..setClientAuthorities('path/to/client.crt', password: 'password');
client.secure = true;
client.securityContext = context;
```

Code from: https://emqx.medium.com/using-mqtt-in-the-flutter-project-6a5d90179c8b

I keep studying the [mqtt_client](https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client) package, but the examples and documents they provide don't seem to have the option to use `.p12` file to establish socket connection.

If I have to download the `.p12` file to mobile then extract and resave three files again, it would not make sense to use Flutter.

Is there any way I can use `.p12` file in the [mqtt_client](https://pub.dev/packages/mqtt_client) package, or is there any other option or package can achieve this?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out that I could insert the `p12` file using `client.connect`, but the package document never said anything about this. This suppose to be a very common way to build MQTT connection.

```
    _client = MqttServerClient.withPort(_host!, _identifier, _port);
    _client?.keepAlivePeriod = 60;
    _client?.logging(on: true);
    _client?.setProtocolV311();
    _client?.secure = true;

    final securityContext = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
    securityContext.setClientAuthorities('$_certPath/ios.p12', password: '');
    securityContext.useCertificateChain('$_certPath/ios.p12', password: '');
    securityContext.usePrivateKey('$_certPath/ios.p12', password: '');
    _client?.securityContext = securityContext;
```